# Current request is not a multipart request problem with sending image from angular to springboot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I want to send an image and a form from angular8 frontend to a spring boot backend and I am using JWT 
every time I try to send the post request it keep getting the same error over and over "Current request is not a multipart request".
I tried to use application/multipart/form-data content-type but it keep getting the same error,
i even ignored the content-type but then it gets a cors error.
please if any one have a solution help me.

frontend code
service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InscriptionService {
  mainUrl:String = "http://192.168.1.70:8080/";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  inscription(formData: FormData):Observable<any>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

  });
    return this.httpClient.post(this.mainUrl+"inscription",formData, { headers: headers });
  } 
}
```

my Backend code

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/inscription", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean inscription(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] file,@RequestParam("user") String user ) throws IOException{
        saveUploadedFiles(file);
        System.out.println(file[0].toString());
        User userf = new ObjectMapper().readValue(user, User.class);
        System.out.println(userf.getEmail());
        System.out.println("hello");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The correct media type is multipart/form-data. Spring Boot has a MediaType enum. You can just look for the values there (or just use google).

Comment: even if i use multipart/form-data it keep getting the same error

Comment: Edit your question, and post the fixed code you tried.

Comment: Read my comment again. The correct media type is multipart/form-data. Your code doesn't use that. It uses application/multipart/form-data.

Comment: the problem is if I use multipart/form-data it get me this error Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.70:8080/inscription' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  and if I use application/multipart/form-data it get the Current request is not a multipart reques

Comment: Sending an incorrect mime type is not what will fx your CORS configuration. Use the correct mime type, and then fix the next issue.

Comment: the problem is  solved i deleted the content-type and it worked Thanks for your help JB Nizet